# XSLT Filter's the complete tag, with child elements but need to filter an child tag using the count reference

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to XML and XSLT.

Currently I am trying to filter some information from an XML file using XSLT.

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>938387</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>TX</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>John</first-name>
    <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
        <license>
            <number>1762539</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>CA</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
<Person>
    <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
    <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
    <first-name>Mike</first-name>
    <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
    <licenses>
        <license>
            <number>17294083</number>
            <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
            <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
        </license>
    </licenses>
    <appointments>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>IL</state>
                <state>NY</state>
                <state>CA</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
        <appointment-info>
            <code>5124</code>
            <number>14920329324</number>
            <licensed-states>
                <state>NY</state>
            </licensed-states>
        </appointment-info>
    </appointments>
</Person>
</People>
```

This is my XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" method="xml" version="1.0"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="appointment-info[licensed-states/state!=ancestor::Person/licenses/license/state]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is how I am getting the output which is not correct,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>Mike</first-name>
  <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>938387</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments>
     <appointment-info>
        <code>5124</code>
        <number>14920329324</number>
        <licensed-states>
           <state>TX</state>
        </licensed-states>
     </appointment-info>
  </appointments>
</Person>
<Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>John</first-name>
  <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>1762539</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
     <license>
        <number>1762539</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments/>
</Person>
<Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>Mike</first-name>
  <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>17294083</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments/>
</Person>
</People>
```

Basically what I am trying to do is, only filter the `<state>CA</state>` from `appointment-info/licensed-states` if the person is not having license for that state in `licenses/license/state`.

And filter `<appointment-info>` if that's the only state.

Currently what is happening is that for third person in the XML file, its filtering `<appointment-info>` but I want it to only filter the `<state></state>` which didn't match.

The implementation only fails when there are multiple `<state>` in licensed-states

This is how I want the output to be: I am not sure how to implement a count on my current implementation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<People>
<Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>Mike</first-name>
  <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>938387</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments>
     <appointment-info>
        <code>5124</code>
        <number>14920329324</number>
        <licensed-states>
           <state>TX</state>
        </licensed-states>
     </appointment-info>
  </appointments>
 </Person>
 <Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>John</first-name>
  <last-name>Jhonny</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>1762539</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">TX</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
     <license>
        <number>1762539</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">NY</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments/>
 </Person>
 <Person>
  <required-tag1>some-information</required-tag1>
  <required-tag2>some-information</required-tag2>
  <first-name>Mike</first-name>
  <last-name>Hewitt</last-name>
  <licenses>
     <license>
        <number>17294083</number>
        <state xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">IL</state>
        <field xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">Health</field>
     </license>
  </licenses>
  <appointments>
     <appointment-info>
        <code>5124</code>
        <number>14920329324</number>
        <licensed-states>
           <state>IL</state>
        </licensed-states>
     </appointment-info>
  </appointments>
```

Can someone guide me how to implement the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is difficult to understand your description. Would the following stylesheet work for you? It does these two things:

- any appointment where the person is not licensed for *any* of the states listed in the appointment is removed completely;
- if a person is licensed for *some* of the states listed in the appointment, then the appointment is kept and the states for which the person is *not* licensed are removed from the list.

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="appointment-info[not(licensed-states/state=ancestor::Person/licenses/license/state)]"/>
<xsl:template match="licensed-states/state[not(.=ancestor::Person/licenses/license/state)]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much for helping me out, you have helped me with some more questions. I want to say that you are really knowledgeable and expert in XSLT. Thank you.